# asp-route does not generate expected url

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

When I use the asp-route tag it does not return the exact url. Neither Url.RouteUrl. They return the home url. But using asp-controller and asp-action, returns the expected url.

```
<a asp-route="Voucher_getPrice" data-ng-href="@Url.RouteUrl("Voucher_getPrice", new { productId = 5})" asp-route-productId="5"></a>
```

From the home page, the generated link is: `/Home/Index/5`

Here is the route in Startup.cs:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
routes.MapRoute(
                    "Voucher_getPrice",
                    "{controller}/{action}/{productId:required}",
                    new { controller = "Voucher", action = "getPrice" }
                    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`asp-route` should not be used with `asp-controller` and `asp-action`. In other word, you can't setup the template that way on `MapRoute()`. Instead, you will have to specify the controller and action name in the template.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "voucher_getPrice",

        // You don't need :required filter. If you don't put ? there,
        // it's required.
        template: "voucher/getPrice/{productId}"
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=home}/{action=index}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: It did not work. When I access the link it returns 404 code. But work with this template: `{controller=Voucher}/{action=GetPrice}/{productId}` the action code is `public IActionResult GetPrice(int productId)`. The controller class name is: `VoucherController`

Comment: Well I assumed you have your default routing configured after "voucher_getPrice". Anyway, see my updates.

Comment: This is exactly how I have my routes configured. But my default route does not have the `id` parameter. That's why when I access the link `/voucher/getPrice` works but, not with the parameter. When I remove the default route the link `/voucher/getPrice` returns 404. So the route `template: "voucher/getPrice/{productId}"` is invalid.

Comment: You just stated the reasons why it was not working. You need to have the default route in order for the route `voucher/getPrice/{productId}` to call the correct controller and action. Or yea you can use `{controller=Voucher}/{action=GetPrice}/{productId}` if you want all requests like 'xx/xxx/ to call voucher controller getPrice action.

Comment: That's the problem. My default route does not have any parameter. it matches any route without parameter. But does not match my route with parameter in the case of `voucher/getPrice/{productId}`.  I want to remove the default route so it matches only `/` like In symfony PHP. In symfony PHP if I say a route must have a parameter, the default route that mathes `/` won't call the controller action if the link is `/hello`.

Comment: What I want is that: the default route `{controller=Voucher}/{action=GetPrice}` should match only links like `/controller/action` that the controller action does not receive any parameter. It does not have to match the link `/controller/action` that the controller action accept one or more parameter. Do you understand the problem(What I'm trying to say)?

Comment: Sorry I don't think I understand your problem. If you want the default route to be any link like `/controller/action` without any parameter (i.e., query string), you can just take `/{id?}` part out of the default routing template.

Comment: Nope, you did not understand. **My default route doesn't have any parameter**. I cannot set the default route template as a fixed path as `/` because, it looks like ASP.Net core does not allow it. For example, if I set all my routes as `/controller/action` instead of `{controller}/{action}`, the application will be break (any link will throw 404). So I have the default route `{controller=myController}/{action=index}`. And another route `{anotherController}/{myAction}/{param}`.

Comment: When I access the link `anotherController/myAction` it should not call `myAction` action, it should throw 404 error. But ,because of the default route, it shows me the page `{anotherController}/{myAction}` without the parameter.